Ubuntu not booting on Toshiba Satellite C660
Newbie here and I'm writing in relation to the above mentioned laptop.
It's an old machine from 2012 that runs just fine with Windows 7, but for the past couple of weeks I kept trying to install the latest verions of Ubuntu, Fedora, Mint or Lite but to no success. All fail to boot.
The installation runs flawless from the USB stick, but the moment I remove the USB and restart, it fails to boot from the hdd ("HDD/SSD xxxx is failed").
I used two different HDD and two different SSDs. I tried Balena and Rufus to create the USB. I Updated the BIOS to 2.0, made sure that secure boot is disabled. Still, not booting. For some reason, grub doesn't load in BIOS.
Is my laptop simply too old, or what could it be?
Very much appreciate your help.
P.S. I think I will close the question and move it to the forum. Wasn't sure if should I ask here or on a forum

You've provided no specifics as to what Ubuntu product, what release of that product, and importantly if you followed documented procedures in trying to write ISO to media & then install. The oldest device I use in QA for current Ubuntu Desktop (& flavors) is a 2005 HP Compaq which is older than yours; but I do follow the documented instructions, as ISO writes using options to reformat ISO make the ISO specific to certain hardware; you gave no clues as to what you did, what ISO/installer you tried etc

If you reformat an ISO during writing to your install media; you can get a failure to write boot loader, meaning it'll initially install but then post-install fail to boot; the fix is to use options when writing the ISO that match your hardware, or just clone (ie. write the ISO unchanged via options) to your install media so all options are taken from within ISO itself... I suggest contrasting what you did, against the instructions for installing your selected Ubuntu product & release.  For us to help we need specifics as to what was done, not vague clues.

Calm down cowboy, that's why i started my post with "Newbie here...". I tried Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 and followed the instructions provided by ubuntu.com. I downloaded the  iso than i wrote it on a USB stick using Rufus and then i tried Balena etcher using the instructions on ubuntu.com. Not sure what options are you talking about. With Balena Etcher i just had to drag and drop the iso, while with Rufus, I just had to make sure MBR is selected, because the system has Bios (not uefi).

Selecting options like your selection of MBR will make the ISO bootable/installable on some devices but not others; if using options at ISO write time be very aware of what you choose & ensure version of ISO writing software is valid for ISO being written (they need to match).  The ISO has details internally which is why a clone will install of legacy BIOS hardware (pre-2010), or uEFI (2009 & later) and even modern Secure-boot uEFI (2014 & later). Comments are intended for readers asking questions of OP, reply via edits to your question. Comments get deleted once addressed (Q&A not forum)

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview  if using GNU/Linux or Ubuntu,
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview if using MAC OS to write,
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview if using windows to write   Did the summary screen showing what was going to install match perfectly; as it likely warned you boot sector could have been written to thumb-drive due to your reformat of ISO  (your altered formatting made it harder to detect itself)

This question is similar to: Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@guiverc that's the tutorial i followed to create the usb stick using a different laptop that has windows 10. Had no issues when i created the usb

It is possible, that the current version of Ubuntu Desktop is 'too heavy' for the old Toshiba Satellite. I have a slightly newer Toshiba, bought in April 2013 with Intel i5-3210M CPU and lots of RAM (12 GB), and it can manage Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. so you are close. -- It is possible to clone with Rufus: use 'dd-mode', then you will satisfy the prescription by guiverc and I think you have a fair chance to succeed using one of the light-weight Ubuntu flavours Lubuntu or Xubuntu. If still problems, you can try an ultra-light 'non-ubuntu' Puppy Linux version or Tiny Core Linux.
